# Firestore supported characters for custom IDs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to create a custom ID for my documents in Firestore, I know all the **base 62** (**a-z, A-Z, 0-9**) characters are supported for custom IDs, I need to know about the **special characters** (**- _ * & $ # @ ! ` ~ %** etc) supported by Firestore to use in custom IDs, is there any unsupported special character?

Also want to know about the white space case, can I create a custom ID like **abc 123** ?

Comment: I suggest you try it and catch the error. The error message is pretty specific about what isn't allowed.

Comment: Read the [best practices document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices) which was last updated at 2021-04-20 UTC.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a late answer, but as I was just looking for this information myself:

The constraints on the document ids (and collection ids are) are:

- Must be valid UTF-8 characters
- Must be no longer than 1,500 bytes
- Cannot contain a forward slash (/)
- Cannot solely consist of a single period (.) or double periods (..)
- Cannot match the regular expression `__.*__`

Document Ids may contain space characters.

The naming constraints on document Ids, collection Ids, and field names are fully documented here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits

Google firebase group discussion on this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/bUMpQwGe08k

Comment: Anyone got a regexp handy for validating strings to the above rules?

Comment: I used a function with a couple regex's for clarity, might be helpful:

`function isValidFirestoreKey(key) { return /^[^/]{1,1500}$/.test(key) && !/^\.\.?$/.test(key) && !/^__.*__$/g.test(key)}`