How do I get a LiveData of a list of items matching the content of another LiveData from Firestore?
My android application uses Firebase Firestore. I have a collection of users and a collection of achievements. Every achievement has a list of owners, which are document ids of the users collection. In my ViewModel, I have a LiveData<Achievement> object, and I would like to have a LiveData<List<User>> object that contains the exact Users that are listed in the owners attribute of the Achievement.
What works currently:
class AchievementDetailsViewModel(private val achievementId: String) : ViewModel() {
    private val _achievement: MediatorLiveData<Achievement> = MediatorLiveData()
    public val achievement: LiveData<Achievement> get() = _achievement

    init {
        fetchAchievementData()
    }

    private fun fetchAchievementData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val achievementLiveData = AchievementService.getAchievement(achievementId)
            _achievement.addSource(achievementLiveData) {
                _achievement.value = it
            }
        }
    }

}

object AchievementService {
    fun getAchievement(id: String): LiveData<Achievement> {
        return Firebase.firestore.collection(Collections.ACHIEVMENTS).document(id)
            .snapshots()
            .map { s -> s.toObject(Achievement::class.java)!! }
            .asLiveData()
    }
}

This way I can access the achievement, and the LiveData updates as expected.
To add the list of users to the ViewModel, I tried to add the following code:
class AchievementDetailsViewModel(private val achievementId: String) : ViewModel() {
    private val _achievement: MediatorLiveData<Achievement> = MediatorLiveData()
    public val achievement: LiveData<Achievement> get() = _achievement
    private val _owners: MediatorLiveData<List<User>> = MediatorLiveData(emptyList())
    public val owners: LiveData<List<User>> get() = _owners


    init {
        fetchAchievementData()
        fetchOwnerData()
    }

    private fun fetchOwnerData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _achievement.observeForever { achievement ->
                val ownersLiveData = UserService.getUsers(achievement.ownerIds)
                _owners.addSource(ownersLiveData) { _owners.value = it }
            }
        }
    }
}

object UserService {
    fun getUsers(userIds: List<String>): LiveData<List<User>> {
        return Firebase.firestore.collection(Collections.USERS)
            .whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(), userIds)
            .snapshots()
            .map { s -> s.toObjects(User::class.java) }
            .asLiveData()
    }
}

This does not work because the first time getUsers is called, the userIds parameter is an empty list. That is not a legal parameter for the whereIn call, which expects the list to contain only valid documentIds. I tried passing listOf("") to the whereIn call in case of an empty list, which resulted in the following exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query. When querying with FieldPath.documentId() you must provide a valid document ID, but it was an empty string.. Next, tried altering the method in the following way:
fun getUsers(userIds: List<String>): LiveData<List<User>> {
    if (userIds.isEmpty()) {
        return MutableLiveData(ListOf())
    }
    return Firebase.firestore.collection(Collections.USERS)
        .whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(), userIds)
        .snapshots()
        .map { s -> s.toObjects(User::class.java) }
        .asLiveData()
}

The problem here is that the first time this function is called, it returns a LiveData of an empty list, and this LiveData object will always represent that unchanging empty list. I did try a few other things, but those attempts also boiled down to having a condition somewhere that handles the case of an empty list, and I always ended up with a LiveData of an empty list. Waiting until _achievement.value.ownerIds.isNotEmpty() is unfortunately not an option, since the list of owners for the achievement could be an empty list. What am I missing here? Isn't there a simple way to handle the case of an empty list in the whereIn call?
Edit: To clarify, the expected behavior is for the LiveData<List<User>> to update based on the content of the LiveData<Achievement> I do understand why my implementation does not produce this result, bit I don't know how I could achieve the expected behavior. My guess is that the problem has more to do with the incorrect usage of LiveData than Firestore.


the userIds parameter is an empty list. That is not a legal parameter for the whereIn call, which expects the list to contain only valid documentIds, at least one

You should still be able to pass a string that is a valid document ID, but not a real one that actually in your collection.  I don't know what happens if you pass an empty list, but it sounds like you're saying that's an error.
If you don't have a list of users to filter on yet, and you can't pass an empty list, then just pass a list with a single element of valid document ID that you know will never equal a real document ID.  It will never match any documents, but at least the query should be valid.
fun getUsers(userIds: List<String>): LiveData<List<User>> {
    val ids = userIds.isEmpty() ? ListOf("_") : userIds
    return Firebase.firestore.collection(Collections.USERS)
        .whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(), ids)
        .snapshots()
        .map { s -> s.toObjects(User::class.java) }
        .asLiveData()
}


Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, I did try passing a list of an empty string to the whereIn call, and that causes the following exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query. When querying with FieldPath.documentId() you must provide a valid document ID, but it was an empty string. I will also add this information to the original question.

Then give it a string that you know will never be a real document id but still valid as a potential ID. The rules for valid IDs are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383901/firestore-supported-characters-for-custom-ids

This does not cause the exception I mentioned earlier, but in the ViewModel _owners.value still remains an empty list.

So maybe you would like to edit your question to explain what the real issue is?  If it's not the empty list and it's not the valid document IDs, then what is it?

The first section explains what I would like to achieve. _owners.value should be a List<Users> that contains the users whose id appears in _achievement.value.owners, but I keep ending up with _owners.value being an empty list. Apparently the firestore call is not the only reason for this. Maybe the observeForever in the ViewModel is also not working as I am expecting it to.

That's probably the detail you want to focus on in your question, and not so much about the list or the document id.  I suggest editing the question to be clear so other readers know where to focus their attention.
